# track outbound link click with many different domains

Tags: javascript, tags, google-tag-manager

I am using google tag manager and [this blog post](https://www.clickinsight.ca/about/blog/how-to-autotrack-gtm#url-change) to implement tracking of when a user clicks to a link of an external domain. This is working well, however, I am implementing this where there are many different websites in the GTM, so the domain will be different depending upon which site the tag is firing on.

I have tried many, but cannot figure out how I can say if user clicks away from current domain then fire the tag. I have tried some regex matching but couldn't implement this.

I am talking about the `my domain.com` part in particular from this blog post.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this. There is a variable in GTM called `{{Page Hostname}}` which should be used.